# How can I check whether a room contain fleas?

Tags: fleas, pest-control

I wonder how I can check whether a room contains fleas. It doesn't contain pets anymore, and I don't have access to the pets to check whether they have fleas.

E.g., for bed bugs, one way to detect the presence is to set bed bug traps around the bed mattress.

Answer (score 4):

Fleas are attracted to heat; that is how they sense potential animals to jump on and bite.

One way to detect/remove fleas from an empty room, including fleas that haven't yet hatched, is to set up a lamp (heat source) just above a pan filled with soapy water. The fleas will jump toward the lamp and land in the water where they will drown. Examine the pan after a few days to see how many fleas were caught.

Comment: Related [Can dish soap really be used to kill ticks and fleas?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/17370) (*it takes 24 hours for a drowned flea to be dead.*)

Comment: I'm not an expert on how fast dish soap kills them; just that they can't escape the water and it will eventually kill them. From my point of view I don't care if they are dead or just poured down the drain; they can't bite me or my pets anymore.

Comment: I wasn't picking on your answer, I like it. But you did not mention time, and was concerned about the fleas not actually being dead. Also having this thought [Will fleas get back in my home if I wash them down the drain?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/13527)

Answer (score 2):

The house that I grew up in had an addition on a separate HVAC system than the rest of the house. Once we went on vacation for a week and closed the addition off (turned off the HVAC, etc). Our family dog had free run of the rest of the house while we were gone, but not the addition.

After a week without access to food, the fleas in the addition were RAVENOUS. I remember walking into the addition in white socks and my feet instantly had several dozen black dots on them.

If there are no longer pets in your home, I suspect any fleas that are present will soon start snacking on the humans (so if you have flea bites, you have fleas).

This won't tell you if you have eggs (or hibernating pupae). You can encourage adult fleas to emerge by increasing the room's temperature and humidity.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy a [flea trap](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&safe=active&q=flea+trap). For example:

[image]

[image]